# Separate calculation and plotting in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to build a shiny app, that runs a simulation and then shows the 3 result plots (I have set them up with `tabsetPanel()`). The code needs a few seconds to run, so I made a `submitButton()`. Now as the code takes longer, I want it to run only once and then display the 3 plots. 
How do I run the code with the input values, extract the 5 result vectors and only then plot them?

Currently shiny gives an error, because when the code is not within the `output$plot <- renderPlot({ ...})` part, it is not reactive.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("My Simulation"),
submitButton(text="RUN SIMULATION")

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot 1", plotOutput("p1")), 
      tabPanel("Plot 2", plotOutput("p2")), 
      tabPanel("Plot 3", plotOutput("p3"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  v<-reactiveValues(v1=0,v2=0,v3,v4=0,v5=0)
  observeEvent(input,{ myFunction()})

output$p1<-renderPlot{
  plot(v1,v2)
}

output$p2<-renderPlot{
  plot(v1,v3)
}

output$p3<-renderPlot{
  plot(v1,v4)
  lines(v1,v4)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is seperated. To make the plot reactive you have to reference the `reactiveValues()` as `v$v1`, `v$v2`,...
It was assigned to `v` so you would also have to reference it that way. You can actually compare the `reactiveValues()` to a `data.frame()` or more like a list that is reactive.
A list `v <- list(v1 = 1)` you would also call with `v$v1`,...

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Simulation"),
  actionButton(inputId = "simulate", label = "simulate"),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot 1", plotOutput("p1")), 
      tabPanel("Plot 2", plotOutput("p2")), 
      tabPanel("Plot 3", plotOutput("p3"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  v <- reactiveValues(v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = 0, v4 = 0, v5 = 0)

  observeEvent(input$simulate,{ 
    v$v1 <- 1
    v$v2 <- 2
    v$v3 <- 3
    v$v4 <- 4
  })

  output$p1<-renderPlot({
    plot(v$v1, v$v2)
  })

  output$p2<-renderPlot({
    plot(v$v1, v$v3)
  })

  output$p3<-renderPlot({
    plot(v$v1, v$v4)
    lines(v$v1, v$v4)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great! My mistake was actually, that I tried generating the inital reactive values from the input. 
`v<- reactiveValues(v1=seq(0,input$sim_time,10),...)`
In addition I tried to use the submit button, instead of the action button and did not refer to it in the `reactiveValues()` function.